# How to find a culprit BP from memory address in VS debugger causing build error messages in UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, debugging, build-process

I am trying to build out my project, but I keep running into a nasty error message about a BP reroute node... :(

It compiles all of the 1000 shaders and everything and just before it would finish it spits out all these messages below :(

Can't figure out how to find the guilty BP reroute node...

UPDATE:

Managed to catch the error in VS debugger, because the error was coming up on editor startup as well.

Does anyone know how do I find the bp node from this:-

```
ToPin   0x00000213399e1e40 {OwningNode=0x0000021339a09520 (Name=K2Node_Knot_2) PinId={6E845E73-4C10-5543-66DF-808C194A79BE} ...}    UEdGraphPin *
+       OwningNode  0x0000021339a09520 (Name=K2Node_Knot_2) UEdGraphNode * {UE4Editor-BlueprintGraph.dll!UK2Node_Knot}
+       PinId   {6E845E73-4C10-5543-66DF-808C194A79BE}  FGuid
+       PinName InputPin    FName
+       Direction   EGPD_Input (0)  TEnumAsByte<enum EEdGraphPinDirection>
        bHidden 0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bNotConnectable 0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bDefaultValueIsReadOnly 0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bDefaultValueIsIgnored  1 '\x1' unsigned char
        bIsDiffing  0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bAdvancedView   0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bDisplayAsMutableRef    0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bOrphanedPin    0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bSavePinIfOrphaned  1 '\x1' unsigned char
        bUseBackwardsCompatForEmptyAutogeneratedValue   0 '\0'  unsigned char
        bWasTrashed 0 '\0'  unsigned char
+       PinFriendlyName Empty   FText
+       PinToolTip  Empty   FString
+       PinType {PinCategory=string PinSubCategory=None PinSubCategoryObject=nullptr ...}   FEdGraphPinType
+       DefaultValue    Empty   FString
+       AutogeneratedDefaultValue   Empty   FString
+       DefaultObject   0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   UObject *
+       DefaultTextValue    Empty   FText
+       LinkedTo    Num=1   TArray<UEdGraphPin *,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32>>
+       SubPins Empty   TArray<UEdGraphPin *,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32>>
+       ParentPin   0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   UEdGraphPin *
+       ReferencePassThroughConnection  0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   UEdGraphPin *
+       PersistentGuid  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  FGuid
+       ToPin->LinkedTo Num=1   TArray<UEdGraphPin *,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32>>
+       this    0x00000213399d2c00 {OwningNode=0x0000021339a098a0 (Name=K2Node_Knot_2) PinId={2F8E76BD-479D-C97B-4820-F5A1EB362139} ...}    UEdGraphPin *
```

[image: DebugHierarchy]

[image: output log]

[image: callstack]

[image: culprit code]

```
LogOutputDevice: Error: === Handled ensure: ===
LogOutputDevice: Error: Ensure condition failed: MyNode->GetOuter() == ToPin->GetOwningNode()->GetOuter() [File:E:/UE4EngineBuilds/UE4dqsmod/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/EdGraph/EdGraphPin.cpp] [Line: 450]
LogOutputDevice: Error: UEdGraphPin::MakeLinkTo Pin 'InputPin' on node 'Reroute Node' has a different outer than pin 'OutputPin' on node 'Reroute Node'
LogOutputDevice: Error: Stack: 
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4872b217 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!DispatchCheckVerify<bool,<lambda_1891a4392d75b7f5d2bf8cae7bcc3de6> >() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Misc\AssertionMacros.h:161]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb474e9f8a UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UEdGraphPin::MakeLinkTo() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\EdGraph\EdGraphPin.cpp:450]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4123e7b1 UE4Editor-BlueprintGraph.dll!UEdGraphSchema_K2::CombineTwoPinNetsAndRemoveOldPins() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\BlueprintGraph\Private\EdGraphSchema_K2.cpp:6856]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4123dce4 UE4Editor-BlueprintGraph.dll!UEdGraphSchema_K2::CollapseGatewayNode() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\BlueprintGraph\Private\EdGraphSchema_K2.cpp:6764]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3d2d6b38 UE4Editor-KismetCompiler.dll!FKismetCompilerContext::ExpandTunnelsAndMacros() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\KismetCompiler\Private\KismetCompiler.cpp:3705]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3d2d6f5f UE4Editor-KismetCompiler.dll!FKismetCompilerContext::ExpansionStep() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\KismetCompiler\Private\KismetCompiler.cpp:3113]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3d2ee5eb UE4Editor-KismetCompiler.dll!FKismetCompilerContext::ProcessOneFunctionGraph() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\KismetCompiler\Private\KismetCompiler.cpp:3747]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3d2bd35b UE4Editor-KismetCompiler.dll!FKismetCompilerContext::CreateFunctionList() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\KismetCompiler\Private\KismetCompiler.cpp:3866]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb2f387965 UE4Editor-UMGEditor.dll!FWidgetBlueprintCompilerContext::CreateFunctionList() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UMGEditor\Private\WidgetBlueprintCompiler.cpp:117]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3d2ad417 UE4Editor-KismetCompiler.dll!FKismetCompilerContext::CompileClassLayout() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\KismetCompiler\Private\KismetCompiler.cpp:4072]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb42ffc407 UE4Editor-Kismet.dll!FBlueprintCompilationManagerImpl::FlushCompilationQueueImpl() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\Kismet\Private\BlueprintCompilationManager.cpp:1212]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb42ff9d43 UE4Editor-Kismet.dll!FBlueprintCompilationManager::FlushCompilationQueue() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\Kismet\Private\BlueprintCompilationManager.cpp:3020]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb463dc750 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FScopedClassDependencyGather::~FScopedClassDependencyGather() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:442]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e0911 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4578]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb46607caa UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::IndexToObject() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4811]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465df36b UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4185]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e0dfb UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3233]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb46608dce UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3397]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674c6cd UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1312]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c46d UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2861]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c69e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2927]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664a406 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2355]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465eef09 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2257]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb466485af UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:790]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e2f91 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:459]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465fbe29 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!GetPackageLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:745]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674c360 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1208]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c46d UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2861]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c69e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2927]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664a406 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2355]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465eef09 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2257]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb466485af UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:790]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e2f91 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:459]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465fbe29 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!GetPackageLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:745]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674c360 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1208]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c46d UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2861]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c69e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2927]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664a406 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2355]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465eef09 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2257]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb466485af UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:790]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e2f91 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:459]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465fbe29 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!GetPackageLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:745]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674c360 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1208]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c46d UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2861]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664c69e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2927]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664ab43 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2583]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4664a406 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2355]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465eef09 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2257]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb466485af UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:790]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465e2f91 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:459]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb465fbe29 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!GetPackageLinker() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:745]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674c360 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1208]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4674b7a0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackage() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1427]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4478ef1a UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UEditorEngine::Map_Load() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:2619]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb4477dd2f UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UEditorEngine::HandleMapCommand() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:6167]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44765db1 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UEditorEngine::Exec() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:5647]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44fbb177 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UUnrealEdEngine::Exec() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdSrv.cpp:697]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44ae5272 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!FEditorFileUtils::LoadMap() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\FileHelpers.cpp:2561]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44ae5074 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!FEditorFileUtils::LoadDefaultMapAtStartup() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\FileHelpers.cpp:3950]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44ff65b6 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!FUnrealEdMisc::OnInit() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdMisc.cpp:361]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb44fb6ed3 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!EditorInit() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdGlobals.cpp:114]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6a66fb859 UE4Editor.exe!GuardedMain() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Launch.cpp:149]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6a66fbaba UE4Editor.exe!GuardedMainWrapper() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:137]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6a670e28d UE4Editor.exe!WinMain() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:268]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6a67113ba UE4Editor.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() [D:\agent\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb8aac7034 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb8ac9cec1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
```

And these are in the log file:

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000018

0x00007ffb47d6a9a4 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!FSkeletalMeshRenderData::Cache() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\SkeletalMeshRenderData.cpp:307]
0x00007ffb47cde080 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!USkeletalMesh::CacheDerivedData() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\SkeletalMesh.cpp:3440]
0x00007ffb47d12a1d UE4Editor-Engine.dll!USkeletalMesh::PostLoad() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\SkeletalMesh.cpp:2518]
0x00007ffb4666b80e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UObject::ConditionalPostLoad() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Obj.cpp:1067]
0x00007ffb4673d08b UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!EndLoad() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1592]
0x00007ffb46727797 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!<lambda_d7afe02bf9c460bdfe082586fba5c066>::operator()() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1231]
0x00007ffb4674c81b UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackageInternal() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1332]
0x00007ffb4674b7a0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!LoadPackage() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1427]
0x00007ffb44594f6d UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UCookOnTheFlyServer::LoadPackageForCooking() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\CookOnTheFlyServer.cpp:3103]
0x00007ffb445d60d1 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UCookOnTheFlyServer::TickCookOnTheSide() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\CookOnTheFlyServer.cpp:2733]
0x00007ffb444415eb UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UCookCommandlet::CookByTheBook() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\Commandlets\CookCommandlet.cpp:921]
0x00007ffb4446c75b UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UCookCommandlet::Main() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\Commandlets\CookCommandlet.cpp:595]
0x00007ff695f135ba UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!FEngineLoop::PreInitPostStartupScreen() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\LaunchEngineLoop.cpp:3391]
0x00007ff695f0b75d UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!GuardedMain() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Launch.cpp:127]
0x00007ff695f0baba UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!GuardedMainWrapper() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:137]
0x00007ff695f1e28d UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!WinMain() [E:\UE4EngineBuilds\UE4dqsmod\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:268]
0x00007ff695f2036e UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() [D:\agent\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
0x00007ffb8aac7034 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ffb8ac9cec1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
```

I tried adding breakpoints before building, but they are not catched...

How do you debug these kind of errors?

Comment: Which blueprints have changed since the last version you built successfully? At worst, you can try reverting to your last successfully-built version, and importing those blueprint changes one by one (or by halves at a time if there are a lot of changes), to see where the error starts occurring.

Comment: @DMGregory please see my updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the BP by starting the project from VS DebugGame Editor mode.

In the stuff that the debugger catches (Autos) I was able to find the exact name of the BP.